# How to make a gradient shadow button in flutter?

Tags: flutter, shadow, glow

I have that button (screenshot at the bottom). Now I want to add a constant outer glow (Glows are gradient-shadows like depends on button). Is there another possibility to do this than saving it as .png in the assets folder? That would make much less work. Thank you!
[image: screenshot]

Comment: Hello. Welcome to StackOverflow. Please make sure you share your code so that users can help you. Check out the question guidelines: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: @Argen this might help you https://medium.com/jlouage/flutter-boxdecoration-cheat-sheet-72cedaa1ba20

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Now I figured it out this problem by modifying [BoxDecoration](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/painting/BoxDecoration-class.html) like [this](https://github.com/zhukeev/GradientShadowBoxDecoration)

Answer (score 0):

You can also try the following package [gradient-widgets](https://github.com/bluemix/gradient-widgets).

Add it to the dependencies in  pubspec

```
dependencies:
  gradient_widgets: ^0.5.1
```

then,

```
import 'package:gradient_widgets/gradient_widgets.dart';
```

Then use it as follow

```
 GradientButton(
  child: Text('Gradient'),
  callback: () {},
  gradient: Gradients.backToFuture,
  shadowColor: Gradients.backToFuture.colors.last.withOpacity(0.25),
),
```

#### References

- [Gradient Widgets Git](https://github.com/bluemix/gradient-widgets)
- [Package](https://pub.dev/packages/gradient_widgets)

Answer (score 0):

you could try something like this ,playing with container box decoration properties such as gradient ,box shadow ...

```
 Container(
    height: 50,
    width: 200,child:Text("Login",textAlign:TextAlign.center),
    decoration: BoxDecoration(
        gradient: LinearGradient(
          begin: Alignment.bottomLeft,
          end: Alignment(0.8, 0.0),
          colors: [Colors.blue, Colors.indigo, Colors.indigo],
          tileMode: TileMode.repeated,
        ),
        boxShadow: [
          BoxShadow(
            color: Colors.indigo,
            blurRadius: 4.0,
            spreadRadius: 4.0, 
            offset: Offset(
              0.0,
              0.0,
            ),
          ),
        ]),
  ),
```

**result**

[image: result]

Answer (score 0):

```
Container(
          height: 50.0,
          child: RaisedButton(
            onPressed: () {},
            shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
              borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(8),
            ),
            padding: EdgeInsets.all(0.0),
            child: Ink(
              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                gradient: LinearGradient(
                  colors: [
                    Color(0xff374ABE),
                    Color(0xff851EDF),
                  ],
                  begin: Alignment.centerLeft,
                  end: Alignment.centerRight,
                ),
                borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(8),
              ),
              child: Container(
                constraints: BoxConstraints(maxWidth: 300.0, minHeight: 50.0),
                alignment: Alignment.center,
                child: Text(
                  "Login",
                  textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                  style: TextStyle(
                    color: Colors.white,
                    fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ),
```